# Html file (located on the SD card) linked with jQuery mobile shows without formatting when viewed from Android Browser

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile

I have developed a mobile application using jQuery mobile, and deployed it on the server.

When I access the file on the server, from the Android Browser, it loads fine and all the styles and scripts are applied.

However, when I take the jQuery Mobile folder along with my html file and put it on the SD card on the Android phone, and then refer to the HTML file on the SD card (using file:///sdcard/myFolder/myFile.html), using the Android Browser, it does not pickup any of the styles (and jQuery does not run fine) and shows only an HTML page without formatting.

When I did the same thing (accessing the HTML file on a file system like C://myFolder/myFile.html) from Google Chrome on my computer, it worked fine.

What could be the problem with the local file (placed in the SD card) not showing correctly on the Android Browser?

Comment: Related: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2454 and http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html